# Javascript For Loop mezclado con if

Tags: javascript

Este script no funciona adecuadamente. No consigo que salga correctamente las veces que existen en Qui de unos(nn1), doses(nn2) y tres(nn3). En esa cadena Qui, existen 7 unos (1), con lo cual nn1 debía ser 7. Existen 2 doses, nn2 debía ser 2 y existen 5 treses. con lo cual nn3 debía ser 5.

En cambio cuando ejecuto el javascript, nn1, nn2 y nn3 van de 1 a 14, y Quic aunque debía ser cada uno de los caracteres de Qui, en el programa parece que solo tiene el valor de 3.

```html
<script>
n=0, nn1=0, nn2=0, nn3=0, s=0, w=0;
Qui = "13231132311113";
Quic="";
for (w=0;w<14;w++){
       Quic = Qui.substr(w,1);
       if (Quic = 1){ nn1=nn1+1;}
       if (Quic = 2){ nn2=nn2+1;}  
       if (Quic = 3){ nn3=nn3+1;} 
       document.write(n + " " + nn1 + " " + nn2 + " " + nn3 + " " + Qui + "&nbsp &nbsp" + Quic + "<br>");
       n=n+1; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer comparaciones, tienes que utilizar el operador `==`

```html
<script>
  n = 0, nn1 = 0, nn2 = 0, nn3 = 0, s = 0, w = 0;
  Qui = "13231132311113";
  Quic = "";
  for (w = 0; w < 14; w++) {
    Quic = Qui.substr(w, 1);
    if (Quic === 1) {
      nn1 = nn1 + 1;
    }
    if (Quic === 2) {
      nn2 = nn2 + 1;
    }
    if (Quic === 3) {
      nn3 = nn3 + 1;
    }
    document.write(n + " " + nn1 + " " + nn2 + " " + nn3 + " " + Qui + "&nbsp &nbsp" + Quic + "<br>");
    n = n + 1;
  }
</script>
```

Asi deberia funcionarte

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un par de problemas en tu código.

Por un lado, en tus comparaciones estas utilizando `=` que es un operador de asignación, no de comparador. En javascript se recomienda usar `===` ya que hace una comparación de valor y de tipo de valor.

Por el otro, la impresión de resultados debes sacarla del bucle, para mostrar estos una vez procesados todos los caracteres de entrada.

El código resultante sería algo asi:

```html
<script>
n=0, nn1=0, nn2=0, nn3=0, s=0, w=0;
Qui = "13231132311113";
Quic="";
for (w=0;w<14;w++){
       Quic = Qui.substr(w,1);
       if (Quic === "1"){ nn1=nn1+1;}
       if (Quic === "2"){ nn2=nn2+1;}  
       if (Quic === "3"){ nn3=nn3+1;} 
       
       n=n+1; 
}
document.write(n + " " + nn1 + " " + nn2 + " " + nn3 + " " + Qui + "&nbsp &nbsp" + Quic + "<br>");
</script>
```

Si lo que realmente quieres es ir mostrando el proceso, simplemente deja la linea que muestra los datos dentro del bucle donde la tenías:

```html
<script>
n=0, nn1=0, nn2=0, nn3=0, s=0, w=0;
Qui = "13231132311113";
Quic="";
for (w=0;w<14;w++){
       Quic = Qui.substr(w,1);
       if (Quic === "1"){ nn1=nn1+1;}
       if (Quic === "2"){ nn2=nn2+1;}  
       if (Quic === "3"){ nn3=nn3+1;} 
       document.write(n + " " + nn1 + " " + nn2 + " " + nn3 + " " + Qui + "&nbsp &nbsp" + Quic + "<br>");
       n=n+1; 
}

</script>
```